# Making all mathematical operators of a struct manipulate the same member

Tags: c++, struct, operators

I have a struct containing a double and several flags, but I would like to use it in my code as if it were just that double. Is there a way to simplify the following code so that all mathematical operators executed on an instance of this struct are executed on the containing double? My code runs but I suspect that C++ has a very elegant and short solution for my problem.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    double value;
    bool someFlag;
    bool someOtherFlag;

    operator double(){return value;}

    void operator=(double newValue){value = newValue;}
    void operator+=(double valueToAdd){value += valueToAdd;}
    void operator-=(double valueToSubtract){value-= valueToSubtract;}
    void operator/=(double divisor){value /= divisor;}
    void operator*=(double multiplier){value *= multiplier;}
    double operator+(double valueToAdd){return value + valueToAdd;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your conversion operator will allow this to happen without the operator overloads.

Comment: Perhaps [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) solves your problem.

Comment: If this even compiles, it doesn't do what you think it does. Your `struct` does not contain a member named `value`, so all references to that would be referencing a global variable named `value` or something, and only one of those operators seems to modify your `struct` at all, which is very odd for operator semantics...

Comment: What is your struct? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JackAidley it represents one sample of an acoustic measurement upon which the measurement device may set a flag indicating whether it was on overload while measuring. I thought it would make sense to store the value and its flags right next to each other in my data-structure instead of separating them. In my case readability is far more important than speed. I have to do some very complicated calculations with these values and my code now looks less bloated because of the conversion. Do you think that's a bad idea?

Comment: I think it makes sense to store them together, what I'm wondering about is the logic of working on them in a manner that discards half the variable. Do you really not care that the sound has overloaded when you start combining them? Shouldn't the overload flag carry into any calculation that it's used in?

Comment: And if you really don't care then I think you'd be better to simply work with the double _itself_ rather than the struct and it's orphan flag. I.e. do this: `sound.value += 840` rather than `sound += 840`.

Comment: @JackAidley I know it sounds strange but the values are still to be used in my calculations even though the device was on overload. The flags are merely displayed in the GUI to warn the user that his results may be inaccurate. Because I don't have to write .value each time I do an operation my formulas now have only half the amount of characters. But do you think the conversion might cause problems?

Comment: No, I can understand still being used in your calculations but as you've designed it if we have two samples `A` and `B` and `A` is overloaded but `B` is not then `A += B` is overloaded but `B += A` is not. That is disturbing behaviour. I would argue that you should write your own functions and, in every case, copy the worst case of the overloaded flag.

Comment: @JackAidley Your right that is disturbing behaviour indeed. I did not think of this because the flags currently do not matter to the calculations. But as soon as the code is extended this may cause problems. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you change the conversion operator to `operator double &`, you get all the operators on `double` for free, with the exception of `operator=`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    double d;
    bool flag;

    Foo() : d(0), flag(false) {}

    operator double &() { return d; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo x;  // initialized to (0, false)
    x.flag = true;
    x += 1.1;
    std::cout << x.d << " " << x.flag << std::endl;
    x *= 2;
    std::cout << x.d << " " << x.flag << std::endl;
}
```

prints

```
1.1 1
2.2 1
```

(second output is the `flag`).

It may still be worthwhile to also define `operator double() const`.

Comment: Not required for answering the question, but I'd add a `const` overload too.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but which rule in the standard says that `x` will be initialized to `(0, false)` (as opposed to having indeterminate value)?

Comment: @T.C.: sorry, added an explicit constructor.

Comment: I **strongly** recommend you don't do this. Implicit conversions of this type are an accident waiting to happen. You think you're being clever and it works lovely for a while but eventually it ends up being a rabbit hole you don't want to go down.

Comment: @JackAidley Care to give an example of what would go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To turn our discussion in the comments into an answer...

I do not think you should do this at all. As you mention in the comments, your struct contains information from an acoustic measurement, so that it has both a value and a flag indicating whether the noise measurement overloaded the recording instrument. Let me simplify your struct to this:

```
struct Noise
{
  double noiseLevel;
  bool overload;
};
```

Now let us suppose you add in a conversion operator so you gain the ease and convenience that offers. Now you have two noise measurements `quiet` and `loud`. `loud` has the overload flag set whilst `quiet` does not. Now you can do these two operations that a reader should expect to produce an equal result:

```
loud += quiet;
```

and

```
quiet += loud;
```

but because your addition does not respect the flag the two operations produce different values. In the first, the `overload` flag is set whilst in the second it is not. This seems to me be highly disturbing behaviour. Instead, I therefore recommend that you implement your own, type-respecting, operators that preserve the `overlaud` flag in a natural fashion, e.g.

```
Noise& operator+=(Noise& lhs, const Noise& rhs)
{
  lhs.value += rhs.value;
  lhs.overload |= rhs.overload;
  return lhs;
}
```

So that the result of any calculation in which one member has the overload flag set also has the overload flag set.